# Number guessing game. field2 not displaying anything. Anyone can tell me what is wrong here?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm learning a lot about Java GUI recently, and I'm now trying to create a number guessing game where if the we type in field1 goes too high, it will display a **Too high!** in *field2*, and if it's too low, it will display **Too low!** in the same text field. If it's the right number, it will display, **Right number! Congratulations!** in *field2* as well.
So far, the trouble arises where field2 isn't displaying anything, and I suspect that btnNewGame doesn't work as well. Can anyone help me in this matter? Thank you so much in advance, and sorry if this is asked before!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class page339_4 extends JFrame {

int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1; // New game initiator

public page339_4(){
    setTitle("Number Guesser");
    setSize(400, 200);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,0));


    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Guess a number here :");
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
    panel1.add(label);
    panel1.add(field1);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
    field2.addActionListener(f2->{
        String playerGuess = field1.getText();
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(playerGuess);
        if (guess > randomNumber) {field2.setText("Too big!"); field2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);}
        else if (guess < randomNumber) {field2.setText("Too low!"); field2.setBackground(Color.RED);}
        else {field2.setText("Congratulations! Right Number!"); field2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);}
    });
    panel2.add(field2);

    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JButton btnNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
    btnNewGame.addActionListener(e->{
        int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;
        field2.setText("");
    });
    panel3.add(btnNewGame);
    JButton btnExit = new JButton("Close");
    btnExit.addActionListener(e->{
        System.exit(0);
    });
    panel3.add(btnExit);

    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: it probably is being displayed, just empty (zero size) - try setting some size `new JTextField(10)` (or set some {non-empty} text in it, at least for testing)

Comment: What do you think `field2.setText("");` does? It sets an empty `String` as the text of `field2`... You're probably right about your suspicions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the listener to the first field, not the second.
So change this line

> field2.addActionListener(f2->{...});

to

> field1.addActionListener(f2->{...});

Comment: Thank you! I also refined the code a bit by using a method on Random class.

Answer (score 0):

If they are entering numbers in field1, you should addActionListener on field1